# In the use of cnosdb found that sometimes can not perceive the system hard disk space, this is why?

Tags: cnosdb

As shown in the picture below, when the cnosdb cluster is just started, one of the two data nodes can sense the system hard disk space, and the other can't sense the system hard disk space. After waiting for a period of time, the two data nodes can sense the system hard disk space. Does anyone know why this is?

[image]